# Snake game in c++ : check the edge of the table (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a snake game in Qt Creator, but I have a problem to check the edges of the table.

The snake is a vector of points and moves with timer the following way:

```
#include "model.h"

Model::Model() {
    direction = 0;
    tableSize = 15;
    snakeLength = 5;
    init();

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(move()));
    timer->setInterval(300);

    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    qsrand((uint)time.msec());
    egg = randomPoint();
    buildWalls();

    timer->start();

}

void Model::init() {
    snake.clear();
    Point center;
    center.x = tableSize/2;
    center.y = tableSize/2;
    snake.push_back(center);

    egg = randomPoint();
    buildWalls(); }

...

void Model::move() {
    Point head;
    switch ( direction ) {
      case 0 :
        head.x = snake[0].x-1;
        head.y = snake[0].y;
        break;
      case 1 :
        head.x = snake[0].x+1;
        head.y = snake[0].y;
        break;
      case 2 :
        head.x = snake[0].x;
        head.y = snake[0].y+1;
      break;
      default :
        head.x = snake[0].x;
        head.y = snake[0].y-1;
    }

    snake.push_front(head);
    while(snake.length() > snakeLength)
    {
        snake.pop_back();
    }
    headOutOfRange();
    findEgg();
    CheckEnd(); }

bool Model::CheckEnd() {
    Point head;
    head.x = snake[0].x;
    head.y = snake[0].y;

    QVector<Point> tail = snake;
    tail.pop_front();

    if(vectorContainsPoint(walls,head) || vectorContainsPoint(tail,head))
    {
        timer->stop();
        qDebug()<< "Game Over";
        return true;
    }

}

bool Model::headOutOfRange() {
    Point head;
    head.x = snake[0].x;
    head.y = snake[0].y;

    qDebug()<< head.x;
    if(direction == 0 && head.x == 0)
    {
        timer->stop();
        qDebug()<< "Game Over";
    }
    return true;   }
```

With the *headOutOfRange()* function i would like to check if the snake met the wall (first of all the top of the table).

Point:

```
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;

    static bool samePoints(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y);
    }
};
```

my results:
-The program crashes with "out of range"
-The timer stops but too early, and I cant take the snake another direction.

Comment: I guess `direction == 0` is left in your case? (i would use an enum for direction) so it should actually work if you don't move out some other direction of course. did you try and print out some debug values when you move the snake? btw what about some assignment operator for your Point class so you can do `Point head = snake[0];` and other stuff unless you like to copy `x` and `y` over and over again by hand :)

Comment: Can you share code for Point?

Comment: Updated with Point struct